# Get the login username in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Could you please tell me how to in the php to get the login user name.
For example, the login username is :Tom.  Tom users made some record in the website.
When login the other users, like paul. In the website , paul can saw the record is made by  Tom.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('dbConnect.php');
    $usname = $_SESSION['username'];    
    $result = "<br /> Username: ".$usname;
?>

<tr>          
    <td height=1 width=1><?php echo $result;?></td>
</tr>
```

These code only can recorded the login user name Tom. But when I login other users,Paul. It will show Paul.

Answer (score 0):

In your code whoever login that person's name will be displayed not the other person's name.

You can write the query to fetch all login users which are stored in your database and then you can show them in dropdown box.